# Working with rereshApex async call in LWC

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components, promises, refreshapex

I am trying to work with *refreshApex* call in LWC to get the refreshed values for the wired data.

```
@track records;
@wire(getRecords)
wiredRecords({error, data}) {
    if (data) {
        this.records = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.records = undefined;
        this.error = 'Unknown error';
    }
}

//here refresh gets invoked from within the code on inline edit handleSave call
refresh() {
    // notifyLoading sets and unsets spinner property
    this.notifyLoading(true);
    console.log('refresh apex started')
    refreshApex(this.records)
        .then(() => {
            this.notifyLoading(false);
            console.log('refresh apex complete');
        }).catch(() => this.notifyLoading(false));
}
```

In this example execution enters the *refresh* call and I can see the 'refresh apex started' in the console and the spinner on the screen but it never reaches *refresh apex complete* which tells me execution never reaches then part of the refreshApex call.

Is there any obvious mistake here or am I doing something wrong. I tried following examples shown [here in documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex) and [in lwc-recipe](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsDeleteRecord/ldsDeleteRecord.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just documenting answer to this issue which was not very clear from any of the examples I came across in the documentation and lwc-recipe examples.

mistake in the above example was,

```
refreshApex(this.records)
```

this.records that is passed to refreshApex is assigned only with the *data* attribute from the wired result and not the entire result, like this

```
this.records = data;
```

correcting it to

```
wiredResults;
records;
wiredRecords(results) {
this.wiredResults = results;
    if (results.data) {
        this.records = results.data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (results.error) {
        this.records = undefined;
        this.error = 'Unknown error';
    }
}
```

and then, using *wiredResults* in refreshApex call (complete result)

```
refresh() {
// notifyLoading sets and unsets spinner property
this.notifyLoading(true);
console.log('refresh apex started')
refreshApex(this.wiredResults)
    .then(() => {
        this.notifyLoading(false);
        console.log('refresh apex complete');
    }).catch(() => this.notifyLoading(false));
}
```

Fixed the issue for me. Thank you @sfdcfox for [his comment on this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/303205/working-with-refreshapex-in-lwc/303257?noredirect=1#comment469502_303257) which helped me realize the issue and fix it.